# AWS CloudFormation Stack Fails to Update Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alias, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

Whenever I make an update to my existing Cloud Formation Stack Configuration (within YAML template) and make a deploy then I get following error:
`MyLambdaFunctionNameAliaslive failed to update`

One solution is I delete my existing cloud formation stack and deploy again it works.

I have AutoPublishAlias live property enabled within my lambda function, and I assume this issue is somewhat related to unable to update pointer to new lambda function.

Please let me know how this can be fixed, so that I do not need to delete CloudFormation stack every-time I update my lambda function config.

Comment: what if you disable the auto publish alias property?

Comment: Can you go to CloudFormation within the console to get details on the precise reason for the failure?

Comment: @Floh It only says ```MyLambdaFunctionNameAliasLive``` failed to update and in status it shows ```UPDATE_FAILED```

Comment: @SándorBakos I did not checked by removing that, but in any case I would require that field to point my lambda to latest alias.

Comment: @Vidip if you will go to the CloudFormation stack events tab, you should be able to see more detailed description of failure reason